# Create entity in entity framework to map the datatable object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-relationship

I want to map the datatable object on entity framework model,

in DB, I have

```
dbo.testdata
 -column
   -AccountNumber(varchar(19),not null)
   -KeyName(varchar(50),null)
   -Value(varchar(500),not null)
```

How do I define in the model class to map all these objects, since EF require primary key, but all the object existing in the db now are not defined as primary Key?Also, I am using Scaffolding to the model.

```
public int Id {get; }{set;} ? should I be defined like this ?
public int AccountNumber{get; }{set;}
public string KeyName{get; }{set;}
public string Value{get; }{set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your database to have primary key as you also have pointed out correctly that "EF require primary key". Check for these links for more info
[Entity Framework: create entity and insert data in table without primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619108/entity-framework-create-entity-and-insert-data-in-table-without-primary-key) and [Entity Framework: table without primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996782/entity-framework-table-without-primary-key)